# Lua - Match pattern for CSV import to array, that factors in empty values (two commas next to each other)

Tags: csv, lua

I have been using the following Lua code for a while to do simply csv to array conversions, but everything previously had a value in every column, but this time on a csv formatted bank statement there are empty values, which this does not handle.

Here’s an example csv, with debit and credits.

```
Transaction Date,Transaction Type,Sort Code,Account Number,Transaction Description,Debit Amount,Credit Amount,Balance
05/04/2022,DD,'11-70-79,6033606,Refund,,10.00,159.57
05/04/2022,DEB,'11-70-79,6033606,Henry Ltd,30.00,,149.57
05/04/2022,SO,'11-70-79,6033606,NEIL PARKS,20.00,,179.57
01/04/2022,FPO,'11-70-79,6033606,MORTON GREEN,336.00,,199.57
01/04/2022,DD,'11-70-79,6033606,WORK SALARY,,100.00,435.57
01/04/2022,DD,'11-70-79,6033606,MERE BC,183.63,,535.57
01/04/2022,DD,'11-70-79,6033606,ABC LIFE,54.39,,719.20
```

I’ve tried different patterns (https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html), but none seem to work, I’m beginning to think I can’t fix this via the pattern as it’ll break how it works for the rest? I appreciate it if anyone can share how they would approach this…

```
local csvfilename = "/mnt/nas/Fireflyiii.csv"
local MATCH_PATTERN = "[^,]+"

local function create_array_from_file(csvfilename)
    local file = assert(io.open(csvfilename, "r"))
    local arr = {}
    for line in file:lines() do
        local row = {}
        for match in string.gmatch(line, MATCH_PATTERN) do
            table.insert(row, match)
        end
        table.insert(arr, row)
    end
    return arr
end
```

Comment: Try `"[^,]*"` to match empty strings

Comment: [Egor Skriptunoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847592/egor-skriptunoff) is right. Changing `"[^,]+"` to `"[^,]*"` solves the issue. However, you should change the parameter's name in the function from `create_array_from_file(csvfilename)` to `create_array_from_file(filename)`.

Comment: Thanks @Zakk copy/paste error corrected above now

Comment: Hi @EgorSkriptunoff, unfortunately that pattern results in double commas being generated across the entire row, and one added at the end ? `05/04/2022, ,DD, ,'11-70-79, , 6033606, ,Refund, , 10.00, , , 159.57 , ` - any other ideas ?

Comment: Try `string.gmatch(line..',', '(.-),')`

Comment: Thank you so much @EgorSkriptunoff, that looks to have done it..